# Remote execution of a Qt embedded application

Tags: qt, embedded, remote-access

I know that we can remote debug a Qt application ([link](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugger-operating-modes.html#remote-debugging)).
I wonder if we can build a desktop app based on the same code as the embedded one that would be able to remote control the embedded app.

In other words, is it possible to include the job done by Qt Creator when debugging in a desktop app?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QtCreator just connects to a gdb-server running on the host. This means if you actually implement a gdb-client you can of course do this.

But...

1. The application will be in debug mode wich should not be used for production
2. You cannot simply have the same codebase and expect to have a UI on the desktop which controls the remote application

You could actually create a public interface (REST/QtRO-based/etc) to enable a desktop app with the same UI to send requests/signals/etc to your remote application (where they should have the same connects as the app itself)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I had the feeling it wouldn't be straight forward. Now I know what are the available solutions. If I may, I have 2 questions: 1. Why debug should not be used for production? 2. Do you have a pointer (ie link) to get an idea of the amount of work required to implement a public interface? Thanks again :)!!

Comment: 1. Slower execution, bigger libraries and executable, security issues coming with built-in debug symbols. 2. Depends on the complexity of the software. If you just want some button-signals, you could just have a small client/server implementation, if you want the interface to be available to others, probably a REST API is the way to go. If you just want to notify the other side you may take a look at QtRemotObjects or just have a `QTcpServer`/`QTcpSocket` connection using `QDatastream`sending `Integer` from Desktop to Server and on every incoming int just emit the propriate signal.

Comment: Many thank again for such a good comment! I think you gave me all the keys in needed to make my choice. Have a nice day :).